# How does MongoDB compound indexes actually work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I was creating compound indexes in mongodb, I found a weird behaviour.
I created an Index:

```
db.getCollection('Subject').createIndex({a:1, b:2, c:3})
```

it created an index named `a_1_b_2_c_3`.

Now when i am using the mongo find command:

```
db.getCollection('Subject').find({a:1, b:2, c:3}) //it works fine `a_1_b_2_c_3` is used.
db.getCollection('Subject').find({a:1, b:2}) //this also works fine `a_1_b_2_c_3` is used.
db.getCollection('Subject').find({a:1, c:2}) //this also works fine `a_1_b_2_c_3` is used.
db.getCollection('Subject').find({b:1, c:2}) //But this command doesn't uses the index `a_1_b_2_c_3`.
```

can anyone let me know why this kind of behaviour is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes). The index `{a:1, b:1, c:1}` has the prefixes `{ a: 1 }` and `{ a: 1, b: 1}`, so the queries that include filters on these fields will use the index.

Conceptually, think of the index like a B-tree that starts with a filter on `a`, and has sub-trees on `b` and `c` in lower levels. The earlier queries can easily start from the top of the tree and work their way down, whereas the last query (`{b:1, c:2}`) wouldn't have a simple starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to force MongoDB to use your Index, you can fake out the query as follows (I have tested it). In this case I am assuming the values for 'a' in your collection are positive integers only.

```
db.Subject.explain("executionStats").find({a:{$gt:-1}, b:1, c:2})
```

This might have other application functionality implications or if this type of query is a standard pattern create a dedicated index to address the query.